# No living connections Error while Elasticsearch connections in nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am having this problem while connecting the elasticsearch connections.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({ host: 'localhost:9200',
                                       log: 'trace'});
```

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2016-07-19T19:09:26Z
  Error: Request error, retrying -- connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
      at Log.error (/root/git_build/FirstMoveChess/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:225:56)
      at checkRespForFailure (/root/git_build/FirstMoveChess/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:195:18)
      at HttpConnector. (/root/git_build/FirstMoveChess/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:154:7)
      at ClientRequest.bound (/root/git_build/FirstMoveChess/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:308:9)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at emitErrorNT (net.js:1272:8)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Elasticsearch TRACE: 2016-07-19T19:09:27Z
  -> HEAD http://localhost:9200/
```

Comment: Are you sure elastic is running?

Comment: Yes it is running i checked the status with `sudo service elasticsearch status` and it shows it is running.

Comment: What does you environment look like, as in how are you running node and elastic? Are they both running on your bare machine, or are you running one or both in virtual machine/docker container? What do you see when you go to http://localhost:9200 in your browser?

Comment: I am using vm for running the node and elasticsearch. i try to curl localhost:9200 it gives a json response. Show 503 errors.

Comment: Interesting... what's in the JSON response? Are your node app and elastic running in the same vm or separate vms?

Comment: It is in the same vm. json response is 503.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117853/discussion-between-user866762-and-mohammad-shahadat-hossain).

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue.. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: please check if the elasticsearch connection is already working.

Comment: I am getting an error **No living connections** but in my case the ElasticSearch service is up and running.  The connection fails inside a docker container but works outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Docker Container Environment after changing from **http://localhost:9200** to **http://ipaddress:9200** in **docker-compose.yml**

please change the following live in **docker-compose.yml** that is related to **CORS**

Change this
** http.cors.allow-origin=/https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?/ **
into this

**- http.cors.allow-origin=* **

Answer (score 4):

I understand this question is quite old but I wanted to share how you can solve this problem.

1. If you are locally using elasticsearch

First thing you must do is running elasticsearch on your machine.

```
Error: Request error, retrying -- connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
```

Because above message indicates that you're not running elasticsearch locally.

So, visit the [link](https://www.elastic.co/kr/downloads/elasticsearch) and follow the insturction.

2. Docker environment

It gets much trickier here.

First, follow the instruction [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).

And in case you're using node.js elasticsearch client, you have to specify `elasticsearch host` as `172.24.0.1`.

If you use `container_name` or `private IP` of `container` in `docker-compose.yml`, it won't work.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this 172.24.0.1 thing? I'm having trouble getting documents to create using localhost:9200 but I can browse to it just fine in chrome and it doesn't error right away but after 30-40 sec